# Java file won't compile using Linux terminal

Tags: java, linux

I am trying to learn how to compile classes in Linux using javac and running them using java commands.

If I create a class and its main method is simply `System.out.println(1);` then I have no issues compiling.

However, when I start to reference other classes in the main method of a class, such as

```
package com.example

public class Main { 

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Class1 class = new Class1();
    class.printX();

  } 
}
```

It will not let me compile even though `Class1` is already compiled.
I literally just type in `javac Main.java` in the terminal and it replies with a few errors about how iv written the class eg. `Class1 class = new Class1();` is not a statement ect.

Through some simple google searches, I have come across terms such as `CLASSPATH` that I don't fully understand. I have literally just downloaded the JDK and tried to compile away lol.

I am completely new to Java without using an IDE and I've only just started to use the Linux OS as of yesterday (Linux Mint) so do assume I know absolutely nothing. I am also new to posting on stackoverflow so please go easy on me if I'v done something wrong, I'v tried to supply enough information without rambling on. Thanks!

Comment: Some formatting please?

Comment: to compile packages you should be at the top-level of the package in the terminal, in your example in the terminal typing `ls` should list the `com` folder of your package, then compile `javac -cp . com/example/Main.java`. The `-cp` (or `-classpath`) flag to `javac` tells it  option to specify the base directory of the package com.example, in order to locate `Main.java`

Comment: I still get the same errors eg. "error: not a statement". I'm thinking when I compile it, it just does not know about Class1, despite the fact that Class1.class and Class1.java are in the same folder as Main.java. Not sure why, if that is indeed the case..

Comment: Do I have to have my directories set up in a certain way, so that it can find all classes within a package? Everything in my Main class would seem foreign to the system trying to compile it if it doesnt know where to grab Class1.java from..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should not use 'class' as a variable name. It's a key word in Java.

Comment: If you are ever interested in using an IDE like Eclipse or Intellij, they do auto compiling for you, and will raise red line error in this case under 'class' suggesting 'delete this token'.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am an absolute idiot. I swear I was doing everything correctly, yet I was getting errors! 

I have been spending ALL day on this, just to be defeated by something so simple XD 

I normally use netbeans, but I wanted to add compiling from the terminal to my skill set, even if Id never have to use it in the future.

Again, thanks so much!